# How can I tell which ports have been used for reverse SSH tunnels?

Tags: ssh, tcp, ssh-tunneling

I have two machines, `client` and `server`.  `client` has created a reverse-tunnel on `server` with something like `ssh -R 12345:localhost:12345 server`.

When logged into `server` how could I find ports which have been bound to tunnels?  So, in the above example, how could I tell that port 12345 was in use as a tunnel to `client`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that by using `lsof` to check which TCP ports are in state LISTEN and used by sshd:

```
[jenny@willow ~]$ sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep sshd
sshd       1084     root    3u  IPv6 0xffffff0003fed888      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd       1084     root    4u  IPv4 0xffffff0003fed5b0      0t0  TCP *:ssh (LISTEN)
sshd      47607    jenny    7u  IPv6 0xffffff00510a0888      0t0  TCP localhost:12345 (LISTEN)
sshd      47607    jenny    8u  IPv4 0xffffff00410062d8      0t0  TCP localhost:12345 (LISTEN)
```

The top two are the SSH daemon, the two below are a TCP tunnel. (Each one is listed once for IPv6 and once for IPv4).